# How to manage onActivityResult() while using fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, onactivityresult

I have an application with one activity and several fragments.I have a method in fragment that call onactivityresult.when onactivityresult called I need a variable that exists in fragment not in activity,so how can manage onactivityresult in fragment that can manage it and access to that varible?can I call onactivityresult in fragment instead of activity?

I want to call this in fragment :

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if(requestCode==1001){
            iabHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data)
        }else{
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        }
    }
```

the variable that I need it here is iabHelper

Comment: Yes you can. You can override `onActivityResult()` directly in your fragment

Comment: @ChristilynArjona onActivityResult can not override in fragment.how should call this?

Comment: @john `onActivityResult()` is definitely part of the fragment api: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent). Make sure that your _activity_ calls `super.onActivityResult()` if you're having problems using it in your fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used onActivityResult in fragment in my project to upload images . i hope it will help you .

```
  @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            try {
                Bitmap thumbnail = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                        getActivity().getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                Bitmap converetdImage = getResizedBitmap(thumbnail, 700);
                uploadedImagesList.add(converetdImage);
                uploadImagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you,yes you can call it in fragment and every thing works